# AngularJS input with ng-model should be empty in pristine state

Tags: html, binding, input, angularjs

Here is an input element I have in a HTML form:

```
<input ng-model="amount" />
```

As of now, since $scope.amount = 0 in my controller, it shows with that value. What I need is the input to be blank at first. This would allow my users to input data into it without having to erase the 0, while still taking advantage of ng-model binding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove the `$scope.amount` or make `$scope.amount = null`